# Wordpress hide new editor in specific pages

Tags: php, wordpress, editor, admin

I used to use the following code to hide the admin editor in specific pages.

```
function hide_editor() {

    global $post;

    if ( is_admin() && !empty($post) ) {
        $id = $post->ID;
        $pages_id = array(ID_PAGE_BLOG, ID_PAGE_SITEMAP, ID_PAGE_CONTACT);

        if( in_array($id, $pages_id) ) {
            remove_post_type_support('page', 'editor');
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'hide_editor' );
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work anymore since the new WP editor release.
Is there any solution, which do not compel me to switch to the basic editor, using a plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this script to hide the editor

https://www.billerickson.net/disabling-gutenberg-certain-templates/

Just replace line 23 with your IDs

Answer (score 0):

I think the plug-in 'Disable Gutenberg' is what you are looking for?
https://wordpress.org/plugins/disable-gutenberg/

Comment: I don’t want to disable Gutenberg’s everywhere, but only for specific pages. This plugin doesn’t do that, unfortunately.

Comment: It does exactly that. When you install the plug-in check the options page. Uncheck the box 'Complete Disable' and then scroll down to the option 'Disable for Post IDs' and enter the desired ID's.

Comment: I though it would do that as well when I tried, but instead it displays the classic editor.